# Sorting Cross-Sell Products in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sorting, cross-sells, sort

If I retrieve the cross-sell products for a particular product:

```
$_product->getCrossSellProductCollection();
```

How do I sort those products in the same order as the administrator has defined via the admin interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCrossSellProductCollection` returns instance of `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection`

This collection implements following method:

```
public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
    {
        if ($attribute == 'position') {
            return $this->setPositionOrder($dir);
        } elseif ($attribute == 'attribute_set_id') {
            return $this->setAttributeSetIdOrder($dir);
        }
        return parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
    }
```

So you should be able to sort the collection similar to admin by calling:

```
$_product->getCrossSellProductCollection()->setOrder('position');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Adding the code (and clearing caches) makes no difference to the order of the products, which seems to be arbitrary rather than by title, ID, etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It IS working - the array of product Ids is in the correct order. My code for outputting those products from the array is going wrong somewhere. Thank you!